# Does a Half-Orcs furious assault affect non damaging attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

A question came up in todays session. If a Half-Orc uses an attack power that doesn't do any damage (for example, Song Of Discord, Bard 5) can they still apply the damage granted from their Furious Assault racial power?

I allowed the damage, imagining that it represented the characters natural ferocity causing an attack that wouldn't usually damage to actually hurt the enemy. However, upon re-reading the Furious Assault power it states that

> The attack deals 1[W] **extra** damage if it's a weapon attack or 1d8 extra damage if it isn't

(Emphasis mine) Would this indicate that the damage is only applied if it is in addition to the usual damage of the power?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That damage can only be applied if it's in addition to normal damage. The key word is, as you've noticed, the **extra** part. Here's how extra damage is defined:

> ### Extra damage
>
> Many powers and other effects grant the ability to deal extra damage. Extra damage is always in addition to other damage and is of the same type or types as that damage, unless otherwise noted. **Because of this rule, an effect that deals no damage cannot deal extra damage.** However, a power doesn’t necessarily have to hit a target to deal extra damage—it needs only to deal damage to the target.
>
> Example: Valenae the cleric might have an ability that causes her to deal 5 extra radiant damage to undead creatures. That ability means she deals 5 extra radiant damage whenever she deals damage to an undead creature.

Emphasis added. You can only use Furious Assault in combination with an attack that deals damage on its own.

This entry is listed [in the D&D Compendium](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=402), and in a few books: the *PHB3* on p220, the *Rules Compendium* on p223, *MM2* on p217, and the *Monster Vault: Threats to the Nentir Vale* on p123.

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for